# Passing Powershell Array As A Variable And Script Blocks

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am testing a process on passing in an array of items to powershell and I'm having a hard time with the ScriptBlock.  I created a test function:

```
function TEST
{
$ScriptBlock =
{
param (
$BackupPath ="Z:\1\2\",
[array]$DBN, #= @("1", "2", "3"),
$ServerInstance  = "10.10.10.10"
)



Foreach ($DBName in $DBN)
{
write-host "$($DBName)" 
}}}
```

I then call this function:

```
$DBN = @("1", "2", "3")
TEST -ArgumentList (,$DBN)
```

I've tried various methods but it can't loop through and give me back the results.  Any help on ScriptBlock inside a function like this will be useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
# Declare the function
function Test-Array {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string[]] $DBN
    )

    foreach ($DBName in $DBN) {
        Write-Host -Object $DBName;
    }
}

# Call the function
$DBN = @('1', '2', '3');
Test-Array -DBN $DBN;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that method real quick in my main code.  Per my understanding, I need to use an argument list to make it work nice with powershell remote but that's just what I've heard.  Testing now!